# como poner un onclick a mi boton desde Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

estoy aprendiendo Next.js y en mi componente tengo varios botones los cuales les quiero agregar un onclick para probar el funcionamiento, pero cuando lo agrego me sale el siguiente error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props.
<button onClick={function} className=... children=...>
^^^^^^^^^^
If you need interactivity, consider converting part of this to a Client Component.
```

el boton lo tengo de esta manera:

```
                <button onClick={signUp} className="stylesBtn">Registrate</button>
```

la funcion esta de esta manera:

```
const Content = () => {

function signUp() {
    alert("hola");
}
```

Agradezco su comprensión y atencion.

Comment: Me parece que te esta faltando en la linea 1 "use client". Proba con eso.. sino mostra el componente entero porfa.. M Exitos!